# Create an animation signal bar with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I generated a bar with some html elements and javascript. The bar shows the gradient colors from black to red. Now I need to change this so that the colors come up slowly one after another to simulate an animation for a strength bar.I am not entirely sure how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my plunkr so far: http://embed.plnkr.co/FVkKbl/preview

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>


  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='todo'>
  <ion-pane>

    <ion-content>
      <div class="container padding" style="background-color: #fff;" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in colors" class="row">
          <div ng-style="{ 'backgroundColor': item }" style="width:80px;height:8px;">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>

</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Ionic';
  $scope.colors = [];
  var j=0;
  for(var i=0;i<255;i+=8)
  {
    $scope.colors[j] = "rgb(" + i + ",0,0)";
    j=j+1;
  }
})
```

Comment: have you tried using $timeout and have the function you pass in change the colors?

Comment: @9ersRule not sure how to do this on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your plunker is this what you wanted:

```
$timeout($scope.runcolors, 1000, true);
```

[Updated code using $timeout](http://plnkr.co/edit/v0dAVgzMKWmBpI63tKa3?p=preview)

Comment: I decreased the timeout to 100 and its very slow and not smooth. Any idea how to smooth this and increase the speed?

Comment: sorry I forgot to change the other time. Its a lot faster than. I set both 1000 to 100. Now if we can make this smoother, than we are all set :)

Comment: Followup question: How do I make it so that the bar animates from the bottom to top instead of top to bottom?

Comment: Its all good. I figured it out. Here is the updated plunker if anybody needs it: http://embed.plnkr.co/FVkKbl/preview

Comment: The javascript is actually kind of slow when implementing it into a cordova application. I am created another question to see if this can be solved with CSS only.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402377/create-animation-with-css-gradient-and-javascript

Comment: Not sure how fast these are but I did a quick search and found: https://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/